# XCode 5 shortcut to insert new line after

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, keyboard, shortcut

Now I know why people complain about xcode's editing capabilities. I find it impossible to code without touching the mouse for one thing or another and this is very frustrating. Anyway I'm used to Sublime Text so to insert a new indented line after the existing line I simply press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, I can't find a way to do that in xcode. Any suggestions is appreciated as I'm starting to consider appcode but don't really want to do that.

Comment: I use `cmd+right arrow`, `return` for that :-)

Comment: I use ⌃-e and return. Sometimes Xcode accepts a semicolon to jump to the end of brackets (if you haven't edited that much).

Comment: uhmm ya that's how I do it too.. I was hoping for something else. It's hard to believe Apple developers don't get annoyed using arrows or the mouse to move the cursor of to select things.

Comment: I found this keyboard shortcut guide in case anyone need it - http://blog.expressionsoftware.com/2013/01/xcode-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial [-Xcode duplicate line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266170/xcode-duplicate-line) to add custom keyboard shortcuts in Xcode.

Then you can just add a new key-value (of your choosing):

Such as:

`Insert New Line Below Current Line:` `moveToEndOfLine:` `insertNewline:`

in the `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist file.`

And then just configure your keybindings to the shortcut you would like (i.e.. <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

You can also do this for any of your favourite shortcuts that may have been ingrained into your muscle memory from excessive use of your favourite editor. Good luck :)