# How to duplicate a line of source code in xcode 6.2 editor

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am familiar with different editors that use shortcut to duplicate a line of source code. I find that this command is very useful for me but I could not find out how to do it in xcode 6.2.

Do you know how to do it, please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode duplicate line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266170/xcode-duplicate-line)

Comment: I use `https://github.com/zenangst/MarvinXcode` and I use this to install all the new plugins `http://alcatraz.io`

Comment: @chuthan20 thanks alot I think this is a clean and easy approach.