# Xcode 9.x Line Duplication and Deletion

Tags: xcode8

Up until Xcode 8.0, it was possible to customize IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist file. However, now it seems like modifying this file causes Xcode to stop behaving normally (e.g. arrow keys stop working) and it is no longer seem possible to create your own shortcut keys.

Xcode never had line duplication and insertion shortcuts. Previously it was possible to add them in IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist by adding the following in the right places:

```
<key>Insert New Line Below</key>
<string>moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:</string>
<key>Insert New Line Above</key>
<string>moveUp:, moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:</string>
<key>Duplicate Current Line</key>
<string>selectLine:, copy:, moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:, paste:, deleteBackward:</string>
<key>Delete Current Line</key>
<string>selectLine:, delete:</string>
<string>selectLine:, delete:</string>
```

Does anybody know how to achieve the same in Xcode 8.0 or above?

I wonder if developers at Apple use Xcode? And if they check StackOverflow? Or are they forbidden to do either by their employment contracts?

EDIT: In Xcode 9.x it seems to be working again.

EDIT: In Xcode 10.0 it is broken again.

EDIT: In Xcode 10.1 it is still broken and also copy/paste is partially broken, meaning it doesn't always work. (I am still on High Sierra)

Comment: Post this in the private Xcode forum and maybe an apple dev will answer it.

Comment: @DavidH This question is not new for Apple developers, and for years I am observing that they simply don't answer this question. To me it seems like Apple has a policy that features which they don't want to add or don't believe in, they simply don't answer them either. Otherwise all other IDEs, at least the major ones, have line duplication and deletion shortcuts, but XCode has intentionally kept them out, and never told their philosophy behind it. I can't imagine life of a developer without these two critical shortcuts, which are needed again and again while writing code.

Comment: My point is that you are more likely to have some knowledgable person post there, or even on the older Xcode listserv, than here. IMHO. It cannot hurt and will only take a few minutes of your time. In fact, I'll post this on the listserv as I've been on it for years - if I get a response I'll update this topic.

Comment: @DavidH that is perfect, since you are already there. Please let us know if you find an answer.

Comment: Same problem here. Up until Xcode 8 I've had to do this ridiculous dance of replacing IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist every time I update Xcode, just to get duplicate line functionality that every other IDE in the world has but Apple refuses to add to Xcode. Now with XCode 8 this no longer works. It's unbelievably annoying and slow to copy and paste a line of code when one should just be able to press command-D.

Comment: @zeeshan seems like its working again in Xcode 8.1+. Can you verify that?

Comment: @Kirsteins Not for me. I have Xcode version 8.2 (8C38)

Comment: It seems that maybe the last line "<string>selectLine:, delete:</string>" is too much, and it fails to interpret the file…

Comment: you might accept the answer, so that others know it's still working

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Confirmed, still working in **Xcode 14.3** on macOS **Ventura 13.3**

1. open `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist`
2. Add the following lines into the **root dictionary**

```
    <key>Sublime Commands</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Cut Current Line</key>
        <string>selectLine:, cut:</string>
        <key>Copy Current Line</key>
        <string>selectLine:, copy:</string>
        <key>Duplicate Current Line</key>
        <string>selectLine:, copy:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, paste:, moveToEndOfLine:</string>
    </dict>
```

3. restart Xcode
4. go into the `Key Bindings` settings and assign any shortcut you want to the new three commands. Just search for their `key`s.

It's a shame that in the 21st century you still have to manually add such basic shortcuts.

### Caveat

The steps have to be repeated after every update of Xcode.

Comment: thanks for the update. I'll check it shortly. What OS version you are using. I am on El Capitan.

Comment: I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.2

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. I have xCode 8.2.1 and Sierra 10.12.3

Comment: I confirm that it is working for me in Xcode 8 on Mac ElCapitan

Comment: Updating XCode to version 8.3.1 and macOS to 10.12.4 revertedIDETextKeyBindingSet.plist defaults. Needed to re-add the above lines to file and restart XCode.

Comment: @Doms Yes that's the caveat, you have to do it every time Xcode was updated. So you can confirm that it works for you as well?

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me a lot. But it acts a little bit weird on Xcode9.0 & macOS High Sierra 10.13 (17A365). I changed it to:

<string>moveToBeginningOfLine:, setMark:, moveToEndOfLine:, selectToMark:, copy:, moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:, deleteToBeginningOfLine:, paste:</string>

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: @zeeshan could you mark this answer as the resolution so that others can quickly realise it?

Comment: @duongel I marked it as accepted. Actually till version 9, the solutions were still not working so I could not mark any answer as accepted. Now I have finally made sure that the solution actually works. Could you please also add the line deletion markup in the same answer?

Comment: This works on 9.3.1. thanks! Is there a way to adapt this so that it preserves the contents of the clipboard? IMHO, that is one of the main advantages of line duplication in other IDEs

Comment: I can't get it to work with Xcode 9.4.1, it just ignores my addition. I'm on macOS 10.13.5.

Comment: I confirm this solution (current edit is of Jan 27 2018) works on Xcode 9.4.1, macOS 10.13.6 I noticed though for some reason shortcut must contain Command key to work.

Comment: 1) this is great, thank you! 2) is there a reference listing all the possible commands (i.e. moveToBeginningOfLine and whatnot)?

Answer (score 9):

The above answer seems to be broken in Xcode 9.

Here is another solution that I have verified does work in Xcode 9 GM:

```
<key>Custom Commands</key>
<dict>
    <key>Duplicate Current Line</key>
    <string>moveToBeginningOfLine:, deleteToEndOfLine:, yank:, insertNewline:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, yank:</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer left erroneous whitespace when I tried it. This works for me in Xcode 9:

```
selectLine:, copy:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, paste:, moveToEndOfLine:
```